# How can I make a function execute after 2 minutes and then at 2 minute intervals after that?

Tags: javascript

I would like to call a function `saveData($scope.data)`

I understand there is an interval function in javascript but how can I make an initial interval of two minutes and then have that function repeatedly executed after that? I also need to save the new `$scope.data` each time

Comment: Read this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    window.setInterval(function(){
        saveData($scope.data);
    },2*60*1000);
    saveData($scope.data);
},2*60*1000);
```

[online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fzpdG/) (with interval shorten to highlight effect)

Answer (score 0):

The following function will execute saveData after every 2 minutes.

```
setInterval(function(){
            saveData(data)
            },
            2*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
setTimeout("javascript function",milliseconds)
```

function for one time delay. Then use

```
setInterval("javascript function",milliseconds)
```

for specific time delay.

Answer (score 0):

JS does not have a sleep function, you can implement your own function, like this

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

then call from your main function with your desire seconds