# Clear local storage after 2 minutes

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to clear some of the local storage items after 2 minutes using this code

I'm saving current time in the variable like :

```
   let time_now  = (new Date()).getTime();
   localStorage.setItem('otp_save_time', time_now);
   localStorage.setItem('set_otp', value);
```

Now i'm checking the current time with the saved time and clearing the item if time is greater than 2 minutes, but it is not clearing the item.

```
    let time_now  = (new Date()).getTime();
    if((time_now - saved_time) > 2 * 60 * 1000) {
       localStorage.removeItem('set_otp');
       localStorage.removeItem('otp_save_time');
    }
```

Comment: Does `setInterval` fulfill the requirement? Or you want to run it once? Then try to clear the setInterval execution later on.

Comment: How are you running the second code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a function execute after 2 minutes and then at 2 minute intervals after that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533293/how-can-i-make-a-function-execute-after-2-minutes-and-then-at-2-minute-intervals)

Comment: How do you set `saved_time`? What if the user reloads the page so that variables are reset?

Comment: @Barmar: If user reloads the page then i will clear all the variables

Answer (score -1):

would you like to use

```
setTimeout(function(){localStorage.removeItem('your key');}, 120 * 1000);
```

it more simple